# One contact from iPhone keeps disappearing

Tags: iphone

I have one contact saved from iPhone that keeps on disappearing after a few days. The first time I noticed, her name isn't saved even though I know I never deleted her, so I saved her number with her name. A few weeks ago, surprisingly I lost her name again, and finally just now after a few weeks I lost it again.

What is happening? I'm freaking out because I don't know if she's 'blocking' me?

Comment: ? Even if they were blocking you. There would be no way for them to delete any numbers from your phone unless they had it physically in there hands or you are using a syncing option again which they would need access to.  Now saying that. Do you have any syncing going on. For example over iCloud and a Mac or PC. In the past I have had numbers on my Mac addressbook that I could never find on my phone. It turned out that I had colons in the name and for some reason the sync server did not like that. Taking them out fixed it.

Comment: Did you solve your problem .?